# Convert a vdb file to a signed distance field

Tags: openvdb

I need to convert my loaded vdb file to a signed distance field using their fast sweeping algorithm. As input I have 3D grids with zeros and ones. I want to fill the rest of the area with SDF.
To create the input vdb file, First I created a 3D numpy file then I converted it to vdb file. I have attached a slice of my 3D numpy file that I converted to vdb to create sdf from that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwvzr.png)

I have tried openvdb::v10_0::tools::fogToSdf(*grid, ISO value= 0) which is not working.

Please let me know if the post is not clear enough or if you have any more questions for the clarifications.
I have tried openvdb::v10_0::tools::fogToSdf(*grid, ISO value= 0) which is not working.